# R sf equivalent of Esri Identity

Tags: r, spatial, r-sf

Is there an way to perform the equivalent of the identity tool from ArcGIS where all boundaries of spatial data x are retained and areas intersecting with spatial data y are updated with attributes and border from y.

Comment: This question needs a lot more detail and clarity. What is "identity", what is "x" and what is "y"? Please give us some code and example data to work with, and show what you've tried and why it isn't working.

Comment: Identity is a geoprocessing tool from Ersi/ArcGis.  X and Y being two spatial datasets. I use the Sf package for most of my spatial processing and works well for intersecting where you only keep the overlap.  It's not really a matter of a specific code not working, more I can't find an appropriate tool to achieve the same goal.

Comment: I agree with @SymbolixAU that this needs more details. Maybe you could upload a (handdrawn?) image of a small example of x and y with a few regions and attibutes and illustrate the result you want to obtain.

Comment: The R equivalent of this tool https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/identity.htm , very similar to st_intersection() , but keep the entire extent of the first input layer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering in case someone else running into this issue. One of my coworkers helped me get to the solution of binding the results of the intersection of the two layers, with the difference of the focal layer and intersecting layer.

```
arc.ident <- function(layer_a, layer_b){
  int_a_b <- st_intersection(layer_a, layer_b)
  rest_of_a <- st_difference(layer_a, st_union(layer_b))
  output <- bind_rows(int_a_b, rest_of_a)
  return(st_as_sf(output))
}
```

or as a tidyverse pipe

```
arc.ident.output <-  st_intersection(layer_a, layer_b) %>% 
  bind_rows(st_difference(layer_a, st_union(layer_b)))
```